# recommended NAS for wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, network-attached-storage

we'd like to run wordpress on a NAS in our company.
currently we're testing a nas which has a 1,2ghz arm cpu - but wordpress is running terribly slow .. :(
any recommendations for a NAS which can handle wordpress quickly?

Comment: -1 This is just full of wrong. It's Network Attached **Storage**, not a web and DB server

Comment: Also - @Fuxi - start marking some of your questions as answered. You've got 7 questions and no accepted answers.

Comment: is it for internal development or for public site?

Comment: @Ben quite a few NAS devices pitch themselves for wordpress use: http://www.qnap.com/pro_application.asp?ap_id=96

Comment: Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Comment: @Fuxi No problem, and fantastic!  Thanks for reviewing, that's a great help to the community!  Very much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you need to run Wordpress on a NAS? Can you just have NAS for storage and a separate computer/server to run Wordpress?

Depending on company resources, it might make more sense to host Wordpress, either from Wordpress.com or another host to mitigate the cost and expertise needed to run it as well as boost performance.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a server lying around, you can turn it into a NAS fairly easily. If you want CIFS (Windows shares), you can just install and run a Windows server OS with a shared folder. If you want something a bit more purpose-built or with NFS support, look into Openfiler (www.openfiler.com) or FreeNAS (www.freenas.org). Both are free, with paid support available.

For all intents and purposes, most enterprise-level NAS solutions are exactly this, with custom sharing software and either a direct attached storage or SAN backend.